# css inline hack for either firefox or chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I need an inline css hack for either chrome or firefox. By inline I mean the following:

style="*margin-top:this is IE7 hack;margin-top:this is IE 8&9 hack\9;">

I know this is a real fubar way of doing things (not to mention non-standard), but the current set up we are using is forcing me to do this. I cannot implement a javascript solution because I already tried it and it conflicted with the global javascript file which affects hundreds of web pages. So I am forced with an inline style as stated above.

I am already using the above referenced IE7 IE8 and IE9 hacks.

This is concerning a positioning issue in firefox and chrome on a floated element.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Seriously fubar'd
umbre gachoong

Comment: You don't say what you want your "hack" to do. Are you looking to just target Firefox and Chrome? If so, you can't without some scripting language. There's a reason they're called hacks :)

Comment: hack for "either" firefox "or" chrome ....or a hack for both?

Comment: I will probably need a hack for both, just in case. Thanks!

Comment: What is the hack suppose to accomplish?? What is the main javascript being used? There's ways around conflicts.

Comment: Thanks guys. So currently the current tooltip backed by jquery within a huge table ran off the page to the right. So I tried another jquery solution which made the tooltip flow within the table, but this knocked out the global javascript functions for the top nav bar and the footer. Putting in no conflict did not work. So I decided to use css only using inline styles. Everything works with chrome, ie7, ie8 and ie9 but positioning of the tool tip in firefox is off to the right by 20 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to work it out with the following:

```
 <style type="text/css">

   ul li.container a.tooltip2{
  z-index:600;
   }

   ul li.container a.tooltip2 span{
  display:none;

  }


  ul li.container a.tooltip2:hover span{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid #999;
  background-color:#ffffe5;
  z-index:99999;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  color:#000; 
    }


  </style>
```

Using the above with inline styles, (ugh, what a pain in the neck!) worked for now. So the designer is going to look it over tomorrow. We'll see what he says.

Thanks for all your input!

regards,
umbre